# Spring DeferredResult's onCompletion() not being called on network failure

Tags: java, spring

I have a mechanism where client sends bosh request to the server, say 5 request at a time.

I queue them and when server is ready with the response, result of the DefferedResult is being set and removed from the queue.

The DefferedResult object is also being removed from the queue if it's timed out (default time out time is set for all the defferedResults).

The client sends new bosh request when timeout happens in client end or gets the response of a request.

The problem is, when timeout occurs in server side `onCompletion()` method is being called, but in other cases like network error or time out in client end the method is not being called. It's supposed to, right?

**Note**: When time out occurs in client, it closes the socket connection which triggers a network error and thus `onCompletion()` method should be called.

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adbosh", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<List<AdBoshOutput>> adBosh(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody AdBoshInput input) {
    final DeferredResult<List<AdBoshOutput>> dr = new DeferredResult<List<AdBoshOutput>>(Utils.DEFAULT_ASYNC_TIMEOUT);
    final ADConnectorAuthenticationProvider adConnectorAuthenticationProvider = services.getAdConnectorAuthenticationProvider();
    final String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();

    adConnectorAuthenticationProvider.register(ip, dr, input.getRequestId());

    dr.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adConnectorAuthenticationProvider.removeConnector(ip, dr);
        }
    });

    return dr;

}
```